# how to get only one public IP address from ISP to two Routers in the Core layer

Tags: cisco-ios

I have a problem with my core layer. I have given public IP address of 142.48.2.0/30 by the internet service provider(ISP) and the private address is 172.16.0.0/24. In the core layer, I have active and standby router which have been configured using HSRP. the problem is that the public address provides only two ip addresses and I do not know to to make the Two routers share the same Public IP address.
Any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Unless that pipe going to your ISP is bigger than the link between your two routers, OR the link between your two routers is latent/slow I would not even try as the benefits would be miniscule.  However, you would have to have to use MHSRP.  Basically, double up on your private HSRP configuration.

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/hot-standby-router-protocol-hsrp/13781-7.html/index.html

"In order to utilize both paths from the host network to the server network, you can configure Multigroup HSRP (MHSRP) between R1 and R2. Essentially, R1 is configured with two HSRP groups (for example, group 1 and group 2) and R2 is also configured with the same HSRP groups. For group 1, R1 is the active router and R2 is the standby router. For group 2, R2 is the active router and R1 is the standby router. Then you configure half of the hosts' default gateways with the HSRP group 1 virtual IP address, and the other half of the hosts' default gateways with the HSRP group 2 virtual IP address."

Be careful about split-horizon, as I don't know how your ISP is set up.

http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/split-horizon